# How to perform natural sort on a field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have an Elasticsearch `keyword` field called `LocationNumber` that I want to sort "alphanumerically" (or "naturally") so that it is easy for users to read. I have been researching this for days and couldn't find any real discussions or solutions.

What I want is to sort numbers and letters in a "natural" way.

This is the default way that Elasticsearch sorts in ascending order, and is **NOT** what I want:

```
0102, 1, 101, 101A, 101B, 2, B101, CC452PD452, Store102, Store102A
```

This is what I want when I sort in ascending order:

```
1, 2, 101, 0102, 101A, 101B, B101, CC452PD452, Store102, Store102A
```

I saw a natural sort plugin ([here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-naturalsort)), but I think it's too old, and it didn't install for the latest version of Elasticsearch.

Is there a way to implement a "natural" sort either during index time or query time? I prefer an index time solution because a query time solution will consume too much memory.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too. Did you use this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.8/analysis-icu-collation-keyword-field.html ?

Comment: @Hamham Yes, I ended up using that plugin. There are many ways to configure the ICU collation algorithm and this demo will help you to figure out which configuration works best for you: https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/collation.html

Comment: can you give me an example of configuration ? For example, i would like to have "numeric" to ON